# classToPlain transformation doesn't apply with routing-controllers

Tags: typescript, express, class-transformer

Regarding the usage of class-transformer & routing-controllers.
Maybe it's me who doesn't understand the real meaning of class-transformer lib, but I wanted to use it to convert object's received from a server (third-party) and adapt them unto my own model, with different names. Which in theory should work, and it does when console.log-ing the new converted model, or even when JSON.stringify-ing it.
But for some reason, when outputting the model using routing-controllers, it just outputs the same origin object.

**User class:**

```
class User {
  @Expose({ name: 'uid' }) // To convert/rename the "uid" property received from the server
  id: string
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}
```

**users-controller.ts:**

```
@JsonController('/users')
export class UsersController {
  @Get('/')
  async get() {
    const user = plainToClass(User, {
      uid: '123',
      firstName: 'Matthew',
      lastName: 'Michalsky'
    })

    console.log(user)

    return user
  }
}
```

console outputs the expected value:

```
User {
  id: '123',
  firstName: 'Matthew',
  lastName: 'Michalsky'
}
```

But response from UsersController (via routing-controllers lib) is:

```
{
  uid: '123',
  firstName: 'Matthew',
  lastName: 'Michalsky'
}
```

Anything you see I might be missing/doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

right. Response sends back a json data and we can't transfer class names with that.
Therefore if you return a class instance from a controller the `routing-controllers` applies `classToPlain` on it and you get a transformed plain object.

If you want to skip this behavior you should configure `@ResponseClassTransformOption`.

```js
  @ResponseClassTransformOption({
    ignoreDecorators: true,
  })
  @Get('/')
  async get() {
```

As an option you can set the direction of transformation, for example toClass only, then when a class instance is being processed through classToPlain such decorators don't have an effect.